# What is the [office] tag for? Can we clarify?

Tags: discussion, tags

On a routine purge of useless new tags I found and attempted to destroy [msoffice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/msoffice). This led me to [office](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/office) which has <strike>[a significant number of questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/office) but</strike> no wiki or usage guidance.

From the questions it appears this tag <strike>is</strike> was most often intended to refer to Microsoft Office but it also seems to <strike>be being</strike> have been used for [questions about LibreOffice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/780492/reinstall-libre-office-5-2-0) and [other random stuff](https://askubuntu.com/questions/856787/how-to-update-a-small-office-of-ubuntu-computers-without-downloading-multiple-co)

What is this tag supposed to be for? I will very happily write a wiki and usage guidance for it if I know what they should say. I am also willing to make a new tag with a better name and/or retag all these questions if folks think that is a better idea.

#### Edit:

I have burned the tag thanks to input received.

Comment: libre and ms office both have their own tags, so makes no sense to have a random , non-specific office tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Judging by what that tag's use currently is, I'd suggest that the [office](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/office) tag either be burninated or clarified *at least* to be about office productivity software.

For those not in the loop, office productivity software is stuff along the lines of LibreOffice, MS Office, etc. The standard "work" tools so to speak.

On the burninate side, [office](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/office) isn't really descriptive to the question. If we want to talk about office software, we should use the related tag if one exists ([microsoft-office](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office), [libreoffice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/libreoffice), and so on).

Comment: I didn't actually notice the microsoft-office tag. Great. I've burned the office tag.

Comment: @Zanna You burned an entire tag by yourself in a day? Wow... you are dedicated.

Comment: meh, only 49 posts. Sorry to anyone who noticed the front page getting spammed by my edits haha